# How do I aggregate grouped point geometries with a fixed point in a virtual layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis, virtual-layer

I am creating an atlas for viewpoints (point layer) looking toward a site (polygon layer, one feature only). Each page of the atlas must show the site and either 1 or 2 of the viewpoints. The viewpoint layer has a field "page" indicating which page of the atlas they should appear on.

I'd like to use a virtual layer as the coverage layer for the atlas (the page field on the viewpoint layer is likely to be updated often, and viewpoints may be added or removed), so a fixed solution is not desired. I envisage the query for the virtual layer using "GROUP BY viewpoint.page" but cannot work out how to create an envelope containing those points and the centroid of the site layer.

Additional info:
The following screenshot shows the viewpoint layer (points) and the site layer (polyline). These viewpoint layer shows the locations where photographic surveys were taken. The photos are placed into an InDesign document, along with a key plan showing the geographic location of the photos on that page. Each page has either one or two photos. I'd like to use QGIS's atlas feature to create the key plans. Therefore the atlas coverage needs to cover the viewpoints for that page and the centroid of the site.

[image: Screenshot of viewpoint locators and site boundary]

Comment: Adding a screenshot could help understanding the desired result

Comment: Stripping it back I tried to union the viewpoints that are on the same page, and it returns a null for the geometry:
select Page, st_union(geometry) as geometry
from "Viewpoint Locations"
group by Page